# How to create new fontface color in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to have new name with hex color for use with `set-face-attribute`?

I look at `list-colors-display` but the list is limited. Can I create new color? Something like:

```el
(???? "simplegreen" "#096500")

(set-face-attribute 'term-color-green nil :foreground "simplegreen")
```

Comment: Are you trying to develop a custom color theme?  One of the idioms for that is to `let` bind new color names to their hex codes inside the theme.

Comment: @Dan no, I just wanted to have color for ansi-term that I'll pick from xterm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `list-colors-display` lists only the **named** colors that Emacs recognizes for your system.  These are not the only colors available.

You can use *any* RGB hex value.  Your system might limit the number of hex digits, e.g., only up to 3 digits for each of R, G, and B.  Just precede the digits with `#`. For example: `#03A9C2E55`.

Comment: for reference, this will work: `(set-face-attribute 'term-color-green nil :foreground "#096500")`, thanks.